# "Ring" when I talk with somebody on phone

Tags: filler-words

i am glad to join with you.
this is first question for me in this website.

Which of the following is correct?
Can I ring you back in?
Can I ring you back on?

thanks

Comment: Hey, welcome. The short answer is neither: simply ask "*Can I ring you back?*" without any ending preposition. If you'd like to know the reasons why, it would be better to ask on our sister site, [ELL.se]. Please also note that the verb "to ring", meaning to call on the telephone, is primarily British, and would sound unusual or affected to an American audience.

Comment: @Dan: I don't think it's all that unusual for Americans. [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ring+you+later%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cring+you+later%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+ring+you+back%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+ring+you+back%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cring%20you%20later%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cring%20you%20later%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cring%20you%20back%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cring%20you%20back%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows we use it at around half the frequency the British do.

Comment: @PeterShor My personal experience differs, then. Maybe it's a regional thing. But in NYC in the finance industry, I've only ever heard Brits use it, or Americans affecting British mannerisms. Also, for that reason, nGrams might be slightly unreliable: it'd be counting people *consciously* using a extra-dialectical construction.

Comment: Seconding Dan's experience.  "Call" is used almost exclusively.

Comment: I suggest that this question would be better asked in ELL.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I ring you back?

This doesn't specify when you intend to ring back. The usual assumption is that you will call in a few minutes. Otherwise it's best to be specific.

> Can I ring you back in 5 minutes/10 days?

When specifying a length of time that will elapse before the call, we use 'in'.

> Can I ring you back at 4 o'clock?

When specifying a time of day we say 'at'.

> Can I ring you back on the 12th of October?

When specifying a date we  use 'on'.

> Can I ring you back after the jury has reached a verdict?

When specifying that the call back will happen following a particular event, we say 'after'.

---

I never realised it  was so complicated until I formulated the answer!

Comment: You'd also use "on"' when specifying a particular phone number or device: "Can I ring you back on [your/my] mobile?" / "Can I ring you back on your office line?" (or "...at your office?).

Comment: It gets even more complicated because although we ring back 'on' a date, that doesn't apply to holidays, e.g. "I'll ring you back *at* Easter"  It makes you wonder how anyone ever learns English!